# My NFT image doesn't appear on etherscan

Tags: tokens, etherscan, nft, opensea, meta-data

I've created a simple ERC721 contract and minted some NFTs, as I mint the images are visible on opensea but not on etherscan.

here is my contract, https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x0323f37c60d24842195f2720dead6abc2a639797

opensea link,
https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/legalserviceofprocess-1

this is my metadata,
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmRjU1BoFojoSXLTXjSuddLo2DMNEhS7fjmbknh4kE16tq

Comment: I noticed even the testnet contracts of popular collections don't show NFTs on etherscan .. but the same ones launched on mainnet show the images ....

Comment: Bro etherscan is not for NFT images 
it is just the block explorer 
If you can see them on opensea that means you succeeded

Answer (score -1):

Etherscan can only display data that is stored on the ethereum or testnets blockchains and **your image is not stored there**. Therefore, it is completely normal that you cannot see it on etherscan. It is important to note that this NFT you have minted represents only a proof of ownership of the image/file, and it does not contain the actual image.